# How can I find an element on a list that stores another list in it and get the index?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I was wondering how I can find values and its index on a list that may store another list in it.

I have taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it does not work if there is a list inside of the list that is being searched.

Here is what I mean.
Given the input:

```
["foo", ["f", "g"], "bar", "a", ["b", "c", "d"]]
```

Is it possible to find, for example, `"f"` and also return its index?

I know I could use recursion or something, but is there a faster and more elegant solution?

**EDIT:**

Also, the list may have **more than one** lists in it.
For example, the list could be:

```
["foo", ["f", ["b", "c", "d"], "g"], "bar", "a"]
```

I need this in Python 3.

Comment: Indexes will be 1,4 for the example you have listed, right? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @cph_sto Yes, they would be `[1, 4]` for the example I gave.

Comment: Ok, let me add an answer, let me know if that is what you want ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with arbitrarily nested data, it's hard to imagine a solution that's more elegant that a simple recursive generator. This will return all the indexes whether nested or not.

This will create a generator that find any element matching `v` and yields the index. If `v` is another list, it will use `yield from` to yield the results of calling the same generator on the sublist while keeping track of the list of parents.

```
def find(v, arr, parent = None):
    if parent is None:
        parent = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(arr):
        if item == v:                      # found an item
            yield parent + [idx]
        if isinstance(item, list):         # found a list, pass it back through the generator
            yield from find(v, item, parent + [idx])


l = ["foo", ["f", ["b", "c", "d", "a"], "g"], "bar", "a", "g"]

list(find('a', l))
# [[1, 1, 3], [3]]

list(find('g', l))
# [[1, 2], [4]]

list(find('x', l) # doesn't exist
# []
```

Comment: Sure @MonLiH, I added some comments and details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want!

```
let list = ["foo", ["f", "g"], "bar", "a", ["b", "c", "d"]];

for (let h = 0; h < list.length; h++) {
    if (Array.isArray(list[h])) {
        for (let i = 0; i < list[h].length; i++) {
            console.log(list[h][i], h, i);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(list[h], h);
    }
}
```

The above code will print this:

```
foo 0
f 1 0
g 1 1
bar 2
a 3
b 4 0
c 4 1
d 4 2
```

Comment: That looks a lot like Javascript, not Python 3.

Comment: Oh did not look the tag! Sorry. Will make for you in python! Is the same logic!

Comment: Sorry on my part, I also forgot to directly say python in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the python solution:

```
arr = ["foo", ["f", "g"], "bar", "a", ["b", "c", "d"]]

for h in arr:
    if isinstance(h,list):
        for i in h:
            print(i, arr.index(h), h.index(i))
    else:     
        print(h, arr.index(h))
```